# Trying to create multiple infoboxes in Google Maps that disappear when a new one is clicked

Tags: javascript, maps, infowindow

I am using the infoboxes plugin for google maps. I have these working well - when a person clicks on a point on the map, the infobox pops up no problem. However, I would like the popup to disappear anytime a different marker is selected.

I've found a few examples of how to approach this problem, but I'm having difficulty integrating those solutions into my code. I'm fairly new to javascript and I could really use some guidance!

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Smelting</title>
    <link
    href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&sfgdata=+sfgRmluamFuX1R5cGU9amF2YV9zY3JpcHQmRmluamFuX0xhbmc9dGV4dC9qYXZhc2NyaXB0+a"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .infoBox h2
    {
        font-size: 22px;
        margin: 0 0 4px 2px;
        }
     .infoBox p
    {
        font-size: 14px;
        margin: 0 2px;
        }
    .infoBox a
    {
        color:White;
        text-decoration:none;
        }
   .infoBox p.sitenumber
    {
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 7px 0 2px 2px;
        }
    .siteButton 
    {
        background-color: #465b66;
        padding: 7px 10px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 15px;

    }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {


            // Creating the map
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                streetViewControl: false
            });

            // Styling the map 
            var styledMap = [{
                featureType: "all",
                stylers: [{
                    saturation: -80
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "road.arterial",
                elementType: "geometry",
                stylers: [{
                    hue: "#00ffee"
                }, {
                    saturation: 50
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "poi.business",
                elementType: "labels",
                stylers: [{
                    visibility: "off"
                }]
            }

            ];

            //Calling the map styles
            map.setOptions({
                styles: styledMap
            });

            // List of images
            var images = [  'images/icon1.png', 'images/icon2.png','images/icon3.png'];
            loadMarkers();

            // Zoom and center the map to fit the markers
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();


            // Create the markers
            function addMarker(data, images) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.long),
                    map: map,
                    title: data.name,
                    icon: images[--data["dot-type"]]
                });

                var myOptions = {
                    content: boxTitle
                    , boxStyle: {
                       color: "#fff"
                      , textAlign: "left"
                      , fontSize: "12pt"
                      , width: "250px"
                      , height: "230px"
                      , padding: "10px"
                      , fontFamily: "Arial"
                      , fontStyle: "bold"
                      , background  : "transparent url( 'images/sampleback.png' ) no-repeat 0 0",
                    }
                    , disableAutoPan: true
                    , pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-90,-280)
                    , position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.long)
                    , closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
                    , isHidden: false
                    , pane: "floatPane"
                };

                var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);
                var boxTitle = document.createElement("div");
                var boxNum = data.id;
                var boxTitle= data.name;
                var boxAddress = data.street;
                var boxCity = data.city;
                var boxSt = data.st;
                var boxZip = data.zip;

                var boxText = document.createElement("div");
                boxText.content = "<p class='sitenumber'>" + "Site #" + boxNum + "</p>" +"<h2>"+boxTitle+"</h2>" + "<p>" + boxAddress + "</p>"+ "<p>" + boxCity + ", " + boxSt + " " + boxZip +"</p>" + "<b>"  + "<a href='#'>" + "<div class= 'siteButton'>" + "VIEW THIS SITE DETAIL" + "</div>" + "</a>";

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (event) {
                    ib.setContent(boxText.content);
                    ib.open(map, marker);
                });

                bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.long));
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
            }

            function loadMarkers() {
                var siteUrl = "data/main.js";
                $.ajax({
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: siteUrl,
                    success: load
                });

                function load(data) {
                    for (index in data) addMarker(data[index], images);
                }
            };


        }


    </script>
</head>

<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason one box is popping up for each marker is that you're creating one box per marker. If you only want one box, just create it once and reuse it for each marker. In your case, this would simply involve putting the instantiation code outside the addMarker function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {


        // Creating the map
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            streetViewControl: false
        });

        // Styling the map 
        var styledMap = [{
            featureType: "all",
            stylers: [{
                saturation: -80
            }]
        }, {
            featureType: "road.arterial",
            elementType: "geometry",
            stylers: [{
                hue: "#00ffee"
            }, {
                saturation: 50
            }]
        }, {
            featureType: "poi.business",
            elementType: "labels",
            stylers: [{
                visibility: "off"
            }]
        }

        ];

        //Calling the map styles
        map.setOptions({
            styles: styledMap
        });

        // List of images
        var images = [  'images/icon1.png', 'images/icon2.png','images/icon3.png'];
        loadMarkers();

        // Zoom and center the map to fit the markers
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        // Move the InfoBox creation here
        var myOptions = {
            content: boxTitle
            , boxStyle: {
               color: "#fff"
              , textAlign: "left"
              , fontSize: "12pt"
              , width: "250px"
              , height: "230px"
              , padding: "10px"
              , fontFamily: "Arial"
              , fontStyle: "bold"
              , background  : "transparent url( 'images/sampleback.png' ) no-repeat 0 0",
            }
            , disableAutoPan: true
            , pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-90,-280)
            , position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.long)
            , closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
            , isHidden: false
            , pane: "floatPane"
        };
        var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);


        // Create the markers
        function addMarker(data, images) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.long),
                map: map,
                title: data.name,
                icon: images[--data["dot-type"]]
            });

            var boxTitle = document.createElement("div");
            var boxNum = data.id;
            var boxTitle= data.name;
            var boxAddress = data.street;
            var boxCity = data.city;
            var boxSt = data.st;
            var boxZip = data.zip;

            var boxText = document.createElement("div");
            boxText.content = "<p class='sitenumber'>" + "Site #" + boxNum + "</p>" +"<h2>"+boxTitle+"</h2>" + "<p>" + boxAddress + "</p>"+ "<p>" + boxCity + ", " + boxSt + " " + boxZip +"</p>" + "<b>"  + "<a href='#'>" + "<div class= 'siteButton'>" + "VIEW THIS SITE DETAIL" + "</div>" + "</a>";

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (event) {
                ib.setContent(boxText.content);
                ib.open(map, marker);
            });

            bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.long));
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }

        function loadMarkers() {
            var siteUrl = "data/main.js";
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                url: siteUrl,
                success: load
            });

            function load(data) {
                for (index in data) addMarker(data[index], images);
            }
        };


    }


</script>
```